# calling a sql stored procedure using the rows() method in grails?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, grails, groovy

I am working in a previously existing grails project that has some search functionality built into it. It has created a new Sql object using my SQL Server datasource, and it seems like it is attempting to call a stored procedure like so:

```
def qResults = sql.rows(spCall)
```

where spCall  is a String and looks like this:

```
EmployeeQueryClient 'SomeClient', 1,1,0
```

Where "EmployeeQueryClient is the name of the stored procedure, and the other things are the parameters.

I can't find any documentation supporting this kind of call - is this correct? How would I really do this if it is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code shown above `sql` is an instance of [groovy.sql.Sql](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html). This provides a `rows(String sql)` method that can be used to execute SQL and returns the result.

Generally speaking, I think this `rows` method is a bad choice if you want to call a stored proc, because you have to concatenate the name of the proc and all the args into a single string, which is a bad idea from the point of view of both type safety and readability.

Instead use one of the overload `call` methods provided by the same class, which are specifically intended for invoking stored procedures. For example, if you just want to invoke the procedure (ignoring any results it returns) use:

```
sql.call("{call EmployeeQueryClient(?, ?, ?, ?)}", ['SomeClient', 1, 1, 0])
```

The syntax used here for calling a stored proc,

> {call PROC_NAME(PROC_ARGS)}

will work for MySql. If you're not using MySql you'll need to replace this with whatever is used by your RDBMS to invoke a stored proc.

Overloaded versions of the `call` method enable you to handle any results returned and/or ouput parameters of the stored proc.